# Insert PHP form data not sending to MySQL Server

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I am a amateur web developer learning php and mysql so I may send php/html form data to the sql server. unfortunately, when I run the program on the web server and click the submit button, the sql server does not retrieve the data I entered into the form. I have been trying many attempts. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Business Therapy</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="ba2e2e">
<h1><center>Welcome To The Therapy of Business</center></h1>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

     $con = mysql_connect ("194.81.104.22", "xxxxx", "xxxx");

      if (!$con) {
      die("Cannot connect : " . mysql_error());
      }

mysql_select_db ("db12408543",$con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Business (idBusiness, Name, Description, Time, Date, Location, Room, Speakers) VALUES ('$_POST[idBusiness]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Description]','$_POST[Time]','$_POST[Date]','$_POST[Location]','$_POST[Room]','$_POST[Speakers]')";

mysql_query($sql,$con);

mysql_close($con);
}
?>
<h3>Create A Seminar</h3>
<form action="adding.php" method"post">
idBusiness: <input type="text" name="idbusiness"><br />
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
Description: <textarea name="description"></textarea><br />
Time: <input type="text" name="time"><br />
Date: <input type="text" name="date"><br />
Location: <input type="text" name="location"><br />
Room: <input type="text" name="room"><br />
Speakers: <input type="text" name="speakers"><br />
<input type="reset" name="reset">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">




</form>


</body>
```

Comment: You want to retrieve OR insert data ?

Comment: There are three things you must learn to use: the W3C Markup validator: http://validator.w3.org/, the CSS validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/, and the developer tools in Firefox/Firebug or Chrome.

Comment: I'd like to INSERT data to the database from the form which will then be stored in the sql server for example phpymydmin. When i log in to the server I like to see the record in the table, I am not seeing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo change this:

```
<form action="adding.php" method"post">
```

To this:

```
<form action="adding.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the correct answer and to all those to said the same answer thanks. I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @GlennYemoh no problem. Typos unfortunately haunt us all!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe typo method="post" instead of method"post"

Answer (score -1):

```html
       

    
**My problem is unic plz help me....**

> this is my full code but it normaly when i type information by
> keyboard or menuarl this time it working but when i copy information
> by othe website and fill the texarea or input text this time the info
> dose't submit in MYSQL databse...

plz help me its unic prblem

<form action="?" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    
    <table>
    <caption><h1>Tours Places</h1></caption>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="place" onKeyUp="getplace(this.value)" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tours Places" class="all" id="place" required></td><td><div id="result"></div><p>Only one Place</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select name="states" class="all" id="staes" required>
    <?php
        $query = "select * from states";
  $run = mysql_query($query);
  while($tours = mysql_fetch_array($run))
  {
   $tourstates = $tours['states'];
  
  ?>
    <!-- check box-->
    
     <option value="<?php echo $tourstates ?>"><?php echo $tourstates ?></option>
    
    <?php 
  }
 ?>
    </select></td><td><p>Choose States</p></td></tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td><select name="districts" class="all" id="districts">
    <option value="null">Choose Districts or None</option>
    <?php
        $querydistricts = "select * from districts";
  $rundistricts = mysql_query($querydistricts);
  while($toursdistricts = mysql_fetch_array($rundistricts))
  {
   $distprint = $toursdistricts['districts'];
  
  ?>
    <!-- check box-->
    
     <option value="<?php echo $distprint ?>"><?php echo $distprint ?></option>
    
    <?php 
  }
 ?>
    </select></td><td><p>Choose Districts</p></td></tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="file" name="images" class="all" required>
    <td><p>1260 x 400</p></td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input name="language" type="text" class="all" placeholder="Language" required></td><td><p>Language</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input name="weather" type="text" class="all" placeholder="Weather" required></td><td><p>Weather</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input name="famousfor" type="text" class="all" placeholder="Famous for" required></td><td><p>Famous for</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input name="howtorich" type="text" class="all" placeholder="How to reach" required></td><td><p>How to reach</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input name="besttimev" type="text" class="all" placeholder="Best Time for visit" required></td><td><p>Language</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input name="mostpreffer" type="text" class="all" placeholder="Most Preffer by" required></td><td><p>Most Preffer by</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <textarea placeholder="Tags" name="tags" class="all" required></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p>Tags</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <textarea placeholder="About" name="about" class="all" required></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p>about</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><textarea placeholder="Where to go from this location" name="wheretogo" class="all" required></textarea></td><td><p>Where to go from this location</p></td></tr>
 <tr><td><textarea placeholder="Past the google map's iframe link" name="map" class="all" required></textarea></td><td><p>Where to go from this location</p></td></tr>

    
    
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
     <table width="100%" class="checkbox">
         <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Package</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="package" value="Package"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Weekend</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="weekend" value="Weekend"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Adventure</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="adventure" value="Adventure"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Educational</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="educational" value="Educational"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Pilgrimage</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="pilgrimage" value="Pilgrimage"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Corporate</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="corporate" value="Corporate"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Cultural</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="cultural" value="Cultural"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Wild Life</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="wildlife" value="WildLife"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Honeymoon</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="honeymoon" value="Honeymoon"></td>
            </tr>
            
            
            <td width="17%" align="right">Beach</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="beach" value="Beach"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Mountain</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="mountain" value="Mountain"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">Historical</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="historical" value="Historycal"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="right">River</td><td width="83%" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="river" value="River"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr><td class="offbeat"><input type="checkbox" value="offbeat" name="offbeat" class="all">Off - Beat</td><td><p>Confirm its offbeat or not</p></td></tr>
 
    <tr><td class="dspacial"><input type="checkbox" value="diganta_spacial" name="dspacial" class="all">Diganta - Spacial</td><td><p>Confirm its Diganta Spacial or not</p></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" name="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Discart" class="button"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    
    </form>



<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
@$place_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['place']);

@$placecode = str_replace(' ', '', $place_name);
@$placecode = strtolower($placecode);

@$place_states = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['states']);
@$place_districts = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['districts']);
@$place_img = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['images']);
@$place_language = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['language']);
@$place_weather = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weather']);
@$place_famousfor = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['famousfor']);
@$place_howtorich = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['howtorich']);
@$place_besttimev = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['besttimev']);
@$place_mostpreffer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mostpreffer']);
@$place_tags = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tags']);
@$place_about = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['about']);
@$place_wheretogo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['wheretogo']);
@$place_map = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['map']); 
@$place_option_package = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['package']);
@$place_option_weekend = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weekend']);
@$place_option_adventure = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adventure']);
@$place_option_educational = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['educational']);
@$place_option_pilgrimage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pilgrimage']);
@$place_option_corporate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['corporate']);
@$place_option_cultural = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cultural']);
@$place_option_wildlife  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['wildlife']);
@$place_option_honeymoon = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['honeymoon']);
@$place_option_beach = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['beach']);
@$place_option_mountain  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mountain']);
@$place_option_historical = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['historical']);
@$place_option_river = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['river']);
@$place_option_offbeat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['offbeat']);
@$place_option_dspacial = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dspacial']);

  
 if($place_districts == "null")
 {
  $place_districts == '';
 }
 elseif($place_districts != "null")
 {
  $place_districts = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['districts']);
 }
  
 echo @$place_img = $_FILES["images"]["name"]; 
 echo @$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"];
 echo @$filesize = $_FILES["images"]["size"]; 
 echo @$filetype = $_FILES["images"]["type"];
 
 $submitquery = "INSERT INTO tours(placecode, place, states, districts, images, language, weather, famousfor, howtorich, besttimev, mostpreffer, tags, about, wheretogo, map, package, weekend, adventure, educational, pilgrimage, corporate, cultural, wildlife, honeymoon, beach, mountain, historical, river, offbeat, dspacial, datetime)
 VALUES ('{$placecode}', '{$place_name}', '{$place_states}', '{$place_districts}', '{$place_img}', '{$place_language}', '{$place_weather}', '{$place_famousfor}', '{$place_howtorich}', '{$place_besttimev}', '{$place_mostpreffer}', '{$place_tags}', '{$place_about}', '{$place_wheretogo}', '{$place_map}', '{$place_option_package}', '{$place_option_weekend}', '{$place_option_adventure}', '{$place_option_educational}', '{$place_option_pilgrimage}', '{$place_option_corporate}', '{$place_option_cultural}', '{$place_option_wildlife}', '{$place_option_honeymoon}', '{$place_option_beach}', '{$place_option_mountain}', '{$place_option_historical}', '{$place_option_river}', '{$place_option_offbeat}', '{$place_option_dspacial}', NOW())";
  if(mysql_query($submitquery))
  {
   move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc,"../images/tours/$place_img");  
   echo "<script>window.open('sightseeing.php?placesight=$placecode','_self')</script>";
  }

 } 
 ?>
```